# change values on textbox when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox, textarea

I am building an SMS app and i want to have a checkbox where the user can click if he wants to send a text message. So the question now is when i click the checkbox for SMS text i want it to modify the textbox area to lets say 100 characters. How would i add the following elements to the textbox. Below is what i would like the text box to look after the checkbox is clicked. I would like to do this via jQuery.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkbox").click(function() {
            $("input[name='textbox']").val("placeholder='texbox'");

        });
    });
</script>
<title>Test Post</title>

 </head>
<body>
<form action="test-exec.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not really a place where we write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @bažmegakapa but anywho a solution below. You can change attributes on elements.

```
$('input').on('click',function(){
   $('textarea').attr('maxlength','100');
});
```

Heres a working [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QTpCX/)

Comment: Thanks that helped i just had to add the conditional statement to check if it was checked